# Trying to understand how to connect phrases/clauses with commas

Tags: grammar, commas, writing-style, modifiers, style-manuals

Take this fragment for example:

The snow had come from the north, in the mist, driven by the night wind, smelling of the sea.

It is from John Le Carré's  *The Looking Glass War*. I've seen writers do this, a lot, and I am trying to understand

a) What is this defined as grammatically, and
b) What are the rules for it?

e.g. above, I see 4 free modifiers. Two prepositional phrases, and two participial phrases. Can we do this indefinitely with however many phrases/clauses we want? Or are there specific rules?

Thank you.

Comment: I eschew criticizing my favourite writer. Try reading it aloud; it's very poetic.

Comment: It's not criticism, but rather admiration. I want to base my style on his, I am just not sure of the rules to follow :(

Comment: There are no rules, but it works. I am not going to pick apart the grammar because it's fine.

Comment: I want to be able to use this when I write, this style, hence why I am asking :)

Comment: Look at this parse: The snow had come from the north, in the mist,  driven by the night wind. You can always append an ing: He drove down the street proudly, smiling as he went.

Answer (score 1):

The first preposition phrase, *from the north*, is actually not a modifier; it's a complement. We know that because that phrase is licensed by *come*.

The rest are indeed optional supplements; and yes, you can do that indefinitely as far as grammar is concerned. English sentences can in principle be arbitrarily long and complex — precisely because of stuff like subordination, coordination and supplementation.

Of course, in practice you probably want your sentences to be comprehensible and digestible. This sentence works fine; three supplements are enough to convey a certain mood, but it's not too many, so the reader will not get lost in the wilderness. If you look up the context, you'll find that the whole paragraph is driven by supplements and asyndetic coordinations:

> *It had come from the north, in the mist, driven by the night wind, smelling of the sea. There it would stay all Winter, threadbare on the
> gray earth, an icy, sharp dust.... The changing mist, like the smoke
> of war, would hang over it, swallow up now a hangar, now the radar
> hut, now the machines; release them piece by piece, drained of color,
> black carrion on a white desert.*

It's a specific stylistic choice. The same thing could have been depicted very differently — say, with no supplements at all. It all comes down to style — not grammar.

Comment: Can you explain what 'selected by the verb, _come_' means, Christopher. The prepositional phrase 'from the north' can certainly be dropped to leave a grammatical sentence.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have a site or a book recommendation for me to better read on coordination and supplementation?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That's true, because complements can be optional. But unlike modifiers, they need to be licensed by something. So another test is to see whether it works grammatically with other verbs.  Perhaps I should change "selected" to "licensed".

Comment: @EvangelosAktoudianakis On the grammar level, both are dealt with in this textbook: _A Student's Introduction to English Grammar_.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: There's a conflict in terminology. There are those who define 'complement' say one way, and those who use a conflicting definition. And sadly those who claim that all others are wrong, failing to point out they're using a stipulative definition.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Well, this definition is quite widely accepted. Here's _Oxford Dictionary of English Grammar_ (2nd ed.), p. 78: "Complement.  A constituent (phrase, clause, etc.) that is licensed by a head, e.g. a verb, noun, or adjective." Trusk (1993, p. 51) defines it through subcategorisation, which is broadly the same thing. When it's in several reference books and at least two specialised dictionaries, is it really stipulative?

Comment: Fowler famously gives an overview of 4 conflicting definitions. And [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(linguistics)) points out that different grammars (in the _theories of syntax_ sense) adopt different definitions. John Lawler has stated the way he uses the term (he's a widely respected published grammarian). It depends which camp you favour.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth But you could say that about any term. Even "subject" and "predicate". If there's an established usage — not an ad-hoc coinage in one book — I think it's reasonable to allow people to use a term without giving citations every time. Moreover, here I give my reasoning for why I think it's a complement, so you can immediately see which definition I'm using. McCawley's (and J.Lawler's) terminology is different, but there, a PP can't be a complement at all, because the term is reserved for clauses. So you can see it's a different framework immediately. Nothing is lost in translation.

Comment: You've already said that 'selected by _come_ might be more clearly expressed. The non-mention that a specific definition is not universally used is, if not actually confusing, tacitly saying 'the other definitions are wrong'. // 'Subject' has been discussed here before, with the terms 'semantic subject', 'retrievable subject' etc investigated. 'Sentence' caused a bunfight when some assumed there weren't both semantic and syntactic definitions in play. 'Word' remains in dispute (who is the final arbiter of wordness: when does a candidate become a neologism?)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The reason "licensed" is better is because in some frameworks, "selecting" refers to idiosyncratic verb/preposition combinations rather than general complements, and I want to be consistent about details like this. I don't agree with your second sentence, but I don't want to bore you with this any longer either.